# Associating my food table into inventory/ingredients table

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

So I'm creating an sales and inventory management for a restaurant and I want to make it like, when an item is purchased from the POS, the ingredients of each item will be lessen in my system's inventory.
But I'm having a hard time associating each food with their corresponding ingredients in the inventory.
Let's say I am creating this new menu in the system which is BURGER with menuID key = 1, now the burger is composed of 1 Bun, 1 Patty, 1 Cheese.
[image]

Next is, I will insert this ingredients to my recipe table, which has columns
menuID, ingredientsID, quantity.

and I want it to be save in some format like this...

```
menuID | ingredientsID | quantity 
---1---|------1--------|---1---
---1---|------2--------|---1---
---1---|------3--------|---1---
```

How can I insert it to my database with the same menuID, but with multiple ingredientsID? I will use either datagridview or listview when adding the ingredients (like in the image indicated) for each menu.

Comment: Please include code examples of what you have tried. At the moment this is a bit of an open ended question, there are thousands of possible answers that would meet your criteria. However, my first thought is to execute multiple insert statements for each row using the same menuID.

Comment: I want it to be more efficient wherein I can just insert it with a single statement. All I want to happen is save the ingredients which I put in the listview or datagridview, but with only one menuID (which is the burger)